# JQuery FullCalendar not displaying events from aspx page

Tags: jquery, events, fullcalendar, dynamic, fetch

I have implemented JQuery FullCalendar by fetching the events dynamically from an aspx page. But it is not displaying the events on the calendar. But if I manually add the page response to the events attribute, it works fine. Can anybody please help what would be the issue? Here is my code.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        //events: "GetCalendarEvents.aspx?id=2612&role=supervisor"  --->not working
 // works fine if i add the above page's response to the events manually as shown below
        events: [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "Family Sick - Unsubstantiated",
                    "start": "2011-03-21 08:00:00",
                    "end": "2011-03-22 17:00:00",
                    "editable": false,
                    "url": "LeaveRequestForm.aspx?id=1"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "title": "Family Medical Leave",
                    "start": "2011-04-25 13:00:00",
                    "end": "2011-04-25 17:00:00",
                    "editable": false,
                    "url": "LeaveRequestForm.aspx?id=1"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "title": "Vacation",
                    "start": "2011-04-14 08:00:00",
                    "end": "2011-04-16 17:00:00",
                    "editable": false,
                    "url": "LeaveRequestForm.aspx?id=2"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "title": "Training",
                    "start": "2011-04-12 08:00:00",
                    "end": "2011-04-12 17:00:00",
                    "editable": false,
                    "url": "LeaveRequestForm.aspx?id=2"
                }

            ]

    });
```

GetCalendarEvents.aspx codebehind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim dbAPD As DBAPDData = New DBAPDData()
    Dim util As Utils = New Utils()
    Dim approverID As String = ""
    Dim approverRole As String = ""

    If (Request.QueryString("id") IsNot Nothing) Then
        approverID = Request.QueryString("id").Trim()
    End If

    If (Request.QueryString("role") IsNot Nothing) Then
        approverRole = Request.QueryString("role").Trim()
    End If

    Dim eventsList As List(Of CalendarEvent) = New List(Of CalendarEvent)()

    Dim ds As DataSet = dbAPD.GetLeaveRequestDetailsByApprover(approverID, approverRole, 2) 'LeaveStatusCode = 2 --> Approved
    If (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then

        For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows

            Dim calEvent As CalendarEvent = New CalendarEvent()

            calEvent.id = If(IsDBNull(dr("LeaveRequestDetailsID")), 0, Convert.ToInt32(dr("LeaveRequestDetailsID")))
            calEvent.title = If(IsDBNull(dr("LeaveCode")), "", dbAPD.GetLeaveCodeDescription(Convert.ToString(dr("LeaveCode"))))
            calEvent.url = If(IsDBNull(dr("LeaveRequestID")), "", "LeaveRequestForm.aspx?id=" + Convert.ToString(dr("LeaveRequestID")))


            calEvent.start = If(IsDBNull(dr("FromDate")), "", String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", Convert.ToDateTime(dr("FromDate"))))
            calEvent.end = If(IsDBNull(dr("ToDate")), "", String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", Convert.ToDateTime(dr("ToDate"))))

            eventsList.Add(calEvent)

        Next

    End If

    ' Serialize the return value .
    Dim js As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim strEvents As String = js.Serialize(eventsList)

    Response.Clear()
    Response.Write(strEvents)

End Sub
```

Comment: If you browse to "GetCalendarEvents.aspx?id=2612&role=supervisor" what response do you get?
Maybe its a syntax issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. In "GetCalendarEvents.aspx" code-behind file, I added the following line after Response.Write() and it worked fine.

```
Response.End()
```

Thanks